# How can I prevent spam while letting users email content to their friends?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm working on an app (in PHP & JavaScript) that lets users generate content (short stories), and I want to add in a "email this to your friend" button.

I'm worried, though, that this could be used to send spam.

What are some things I could do to prevent that from happening? I am thinking:

1) The user must confirm their own personal email address before I send it
2) I have a hidden field somewhere that bots would fill in

What else should I do?

Cheers

Comment: Friends do not send spam to other friend. Spam is evil >:-(

Comment: Resisted users only is the best options, otherwise - CAPCHA, don't allow links, don't allow anything other than email address, and maybe one line of added text.

Comment: Do a request via an ajax request (post) with email as a parameter. then send the email on that ajax page. probably restrict that directory to only to your mail ip address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two solutions to your problem.

1) Only allow registered users to send an e-mail. This may be a bad idea if you intend to have this website mainly visited by non-registered people.

2) Add a [captcha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) to the form. This will prevent bots to be able to send anything at all.

What did you see online? How do people deal with this problem on their own sites? Try surfing the web, going to blogs, forums, etc. and see what they use to protect themselves. Maybe they have better ideas than me.

Comment: I like the registration idea - thanks! If people don't want to register, they can copy and paste it into an email themself :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the user can add also edit the story, hence write spam. As part of spamming happens with cheap human users, you have a problem. Simply offer only **download as PDF**. Then they can mail it on their own. No captcha, no unsureness about what would be added to the friends email, or what happens with the address data. So it is something more acceptible even, and might add success to your app. *Drawback you can't mine the data.*

Comment: I think adding in PDF translation would complicate things a bit too much - maybe not. Something to think about... a "Save as PDF" feature could be popular. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also add a rate limit, like 1/minute and 10/hour (example, need to figure out what numbers fit you), if violated block for 1 hour if violated before the hour is out block for 2 hours etc.

Comment: Perfect! I'll only let registered users send the emails, then it will be easy to track how frequently they do it (and I can time stamp each one too). Great - thank you